# How to delete a node with optimisticUpdater in Relay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I am trying to delete a node, and then update the UI using **optimisticUpdater** inside the mutation, but I cannot to update the **store** and update the connection. The mutation itself works, but I want the UI to be updated without reloading the page. If I just delete the node from the store, then the error *"TypeError: edge.node is null"* occurs. I am also trying to access the connection using **ConnectionHandler** to remove the node from the *connection*, but I cannot figure out how to access the connection inside the mutation. I looked at the Relay documentation on mutations and store, but everything is very compressed there, and there are few examples on the network. The documentation says that the Relay Store is the one source of truth for the entire application, but I don’t understand how to access the right data from any component. Please tell me what I need to do inside optimisticUpdater, or somewhere else, to update the UI after deleting the record.

After removal, the mutation returns the id of the removed node. Here is the mutation code:

```
import { commitMutation, graphql } from 'react-relay';
import environment from '../Environment';
import { ConnectionHandler } from 'relay-runtime';

const mutation = graphql`
  mutation RemoveHeroMutation($input: RemoveHeroInput!) {
    removeHero(input: $input) {
      deletedId
      deleted
    }
  }
`;

export default (id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  commitMutation(
    environment,
    {
      mutation,
      variables: {
        input: {
          id
        }
      },
      optimisticUpdater: (store) => {
        //this doesn't work
        const heroProxy = store.get(id);
        const conn = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(
          heroProxy,
          'HeroesList_Heroes'
        );
      },
      onCompleted: (res, err) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve("Removed");
      },
      onError: err => console.error(err)
    },
  );
});
```

The root component in which the request occurs. The Fragment container is used here:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import Line from '../components/Line';

import { QueryRenderer, graphql } from 'react-relay';
import environment from '../Environment';
import HeroesList from '../components/HeroesList';

const HeroesQuery = graphql`
  query HeroesQuery {
    viewer {
      ...HeroesList_viewer
    }
  }
`;

class Heroes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1>Heroes page</h1>
        <Line />
        <Button type="primary">
          <PlusOutlined /> <Link to="/addhero">Add Hero</Link>
        </Button>
        <QueryRenderer
          environment={environment}
          query={HeroesQuery}
          render={({ error, props }) => {
            if (error) {
              return <div>{error.message}</div>;
            } else if (props) {
              return <HeroesList viewer={props.viewer} />;
            }
            return <div>Loadind...</div>
          }}
        />      
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Heroes;
```

The HeroesList component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HeroTpl from './HeroTpl';

import { createFragmentContainer, graphql } from 'react-relay';

class HeroesList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: '10px 0' }}>
        {this.props.viewer.Heroes.edges.map(edge => (
          <HeroTpl hero={edge.node} key={edge.node.id} />
        ))}
        <br/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default createFragmentContainer(
  HeroesList,
  {
    viewer: graphql`
      fragment HeroesList_viewer on Viewer {
        Heroes 
          @connection(key: "HeroesList_Heroes") {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              ...HeroTpl_hero
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  }
);
```

The 'HeroTpl' component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import { createFragmentContainer, graphql } from 'react-relay';
import { DeleteOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

import RemoveHeroMutation from '../mutations/RemoveHeroMutation';

class HeroTpl extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Row className="line">
          <Col span={12}>
            <Link to={`/heroes/${this.props.hero.id}`}>
              <h3>{this.props.hero.name}</h3>
            </Link>
          </Col>
          <Col span={6}>{this.props.hero.date}</Col>
          <Col span={6}>
            <DeleteOutlined
              className="delete"
              onClick={() => { RemoveHeroMutation(this.props.hero.id); }}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default createFragmentContainer(
  HeroTpl, {
    hero: graphql`
      fragment HeroTpl_hero on Hero {
        id
        name
        date
      }
    `
  }
);
```

I would be grateful for your help. I'd love to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could help
[NODE_DELETE](https://relay.dev/docs/en/mutations#node_delete)

relay will get a hint that a node is deleted and will update the require state in the store and hence re-render all the components using that state.

We can give Relay instructions in the form of a configs array on how to use the response from each mutation to update the client-side store